# uA741 OpAmp output current never approaches "TYP" output short circuit current

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

I am trying to use a uA741 Op-Amp (I cannot use a different Op-Amp) to build an amplified half wave rectifier circuit. I was able to successfully build the circuit, however the zener diode that I used which is rated at 3.6V was only outputting about 2.7V RMS voltage. After some testing on another circuit, I found that the amperage was too low to output the required voltage. Unfortunately, I was not provided the part number or a datasheet for the zener diode, so I had to figure out through trial and error that I needed around 50mA current in order to reach the desired voltage.

My new problem is that no matter what I do, I cannot get my Op-Amp to output anything near 50mA. According to the [spec sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua741.pdf), the typical short-circuit output current for the uA741 OpAmp is +/- 25mA and maximum is +/- 40mA. After creating a simplified inverting amplifier circuit as shown below, the highest output current I have been able to achieve was only about 10mA.

[image: Inverting Op-Amp]

I am using 2 9V batteries as a power source and a waveform generator for V_in (1 V, 400Hz sine wave, although I experimented with higher voltages)

I have tried many combination of R1 and R2 such that the voltage gain was around 8 V/V.

These are some of the resistor combinations I've tried, however I have lost track of all of them.

R1 = 1k and R2 = 8k

R1 = 100 and R2 = 800

R1 = 40 and R2 = 320

R1 = 20 and R2 = 160

I expected the current to increase as the feedback resistance went down, but with lower feedback resistance the voltage gain also went down, and so did the current. I am guessing this is due to offset. What I don't understand is how the typical output current could be rated as 25mA, and every single combination I've tried is nowhere near that current. Am I misunderstanding the data sheet, or is there a secret to getting the expected output current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to the spec sheet, the typical short-circuit output current for the uA741 OpAmp is +/- 25mA and maximum is +/- 40mA. ...
> The highest output current I have been able to achieve was only about 10mA. ...
> I am using 2 9V batteries as a power source

Those short-circuit current figures are given in table 6.4 of your cited spec sheet. Note that at the top of the table it states:

"VCC± = ±15 V (unless otherwise noted)"

There is no note on the \$I_{OS}\$ specification so that was measured with  ±15 V supplies. Your ±9V supplies are not enough to achieve the stated specification.

In general when looking for specifications in datasheets you need to pay attention to any notes or conditions attached to the specifications. You can only expect to achieve the stated specification if you also fulfill the small print attached to the specs.

Note that you can't just double up your 9 V batteries to give ±18 V supplies. ±18 V is given as the absolute maximum supply for the 741 (table 6.1). New "9 V" batteries will give a bit more than 9 V (I've seen 9.6 V) and could damage your 741. A regulator to bring the supply down to the recommended ±15 V would be needed.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

The schematic you show works by ensuring that current in R2 is always equal to current in R1. Current \$I_{R2}\$ in R2 is actually:

$$ I_{R2} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} $$

The absence of \$R_2\$ in that equation means that you can't change current anywhere by changing R2.

Also, there's no rectification happening. It's just a linear amplifier, that does:

$$ V_{OUT} = -V_{IN}\times \frac{R_2}{R_1} $$

I don't understand how you used a zener diode to rectify, or how you expected that zener to "produce" 50mA, or anything, your description is too vague. In any case, unless you use an op-amp, or some other active amplifier, you can't get more current out than the signal source can provide, since all current is provided by that source.

It's also not clear what you meant by "amperage was too low to output the required voltage". Usually it's the voltage that we control, which results in some current through it, not the other way around.

You speak of "short-circuit current" as if that's a normal condition. It is not. If you "short circuit" the op-amp output, then you are forcing it to 0V (or some other fixed potential), and that means it's not behaving as an op-amp any more. Sure, you may be able to get 25mA to flow from that output, but the voltage at the output would not be what you want, because you've short-circuited it. In normal operation, you can expect 10mA in or out of the op-amp output, not more.

This limit is approximate, but not negotiable. If you need 50mA, then you must buffer the op-amp output in some way. Since you want to half-wave rectify, then you only need to *source* +50mA (current *out* of the system, not in), which simplifies things somewhat:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1AlcK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here transistor Q1 is an [emitter follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector), capable of sourcing over 300mA  of current into load R1, if required by the load. This responsibility for current provision is removed from the op-amp, so the op-amp's own limit of 10mA or so is no longer a problem. Q1 is only able to *source* current through load R1, not sink it, during the positive halves of the input signal, so conveniently, it will also naturally rectify.

With this input \$V_{IN}\$:

[image]

That's a 1V peak sinusoid, resulting in this output voltage \$V_{OUT}\$:

[image]

There's no gain, so the peak output is 1V also, but the negative excursions have been removed, so this is half-wave rectifying. The resulting output current is \$\frac{V_{OUT}}{R_1}\$:

[image]

If you wish to have voltage gain too, then you must reduce the feedback factor, which is 1 (one) above. For instance, to have gain of \$A=2\$ then feedback should be \$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{2}\$, which you can achieve with a resistor potential divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTOT8.png)</sup>

Now voltage gain \$A\$ is:

$$ A = 1 + \frac{R_3}{R_2} = 2 $$

With the same input, output voltage will now be doubled, and consequently you can expect load (output) current to be doubled also:

[image]

You may have noticed some small distortion in those output waveforms, at 1ms and 2ms. These are caused by the op-amp being unable to swing its output fast enough to recover from saturation. This can be mitigated, but that's another story.